# How to get values from selected row in android listview?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have `ListView`, I populated this `ListView` with values using adapter class. Now i want to display selected row values in another activity.How to do that? 
My Activity:

```
public class SimplePurchaseOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefUser;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;    
    private ListView purchaseOrderListView;
    SimplePurchaseOrderAdapter simplePurchaseOrderAdapter;
    ArrayList<PoHeadersBO> poHeadersBOs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_purchase_order)
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        purchaseOrderListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.purchaseOrderListView);
        searchPOOrders=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPOSearch);
        searchSupplier=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchPOEditText);
        edtFromDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.poFromDate);
        edtToDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.poToDate);
        sharedPrefUser = getSharedPreferences(ISharedPreferencesUtil.SHARED_USER_MANAGEMENT, 0);
        editor = sharedPrefUser.edit();
        new GetPurchaseOrders(IUrlsUtil.URL_PURCHASE_ORDERS).execute();
    ***purchaseOrderListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object obj = purchaseOrderListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //here is the problem ... please check the console error below.
                String purchaseOrderNumber = ((PoHeadersBO) obj).getPoNumber().toString();
                String supplierName=((PoHeadersBO) obj).getSupplierId().toString();
                ArrayList<PoDetailsBO> poDetails=((PoHeadersBO) obj).getPoDetails();
                Intent iPODetails = new Intent(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this, PurchaseOrderReportActivity.class);
                iPODetails.putExtra("poNumber", purchaseOrderNumber);
                iPODetails.putExtra("supplierName", supplierName);
                iPODetails.putExtra("poDetails", poDetails);
                startActivity(iPODetails);
            }
        });***
    }
    class GetPurchaseOrders extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        ResultVO getPurchaseOrderResponse;
        String param;
        PurchaseOrderArrayListBO purchaseOrderArrayListBO;
        GetPurchaseOrders(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                YGTHeaderParms ygtHeaderParms = ICommonMethods.setHeaderParams(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this);
                APIServicesImpl services = new APIServicesImpl();
                getPurchaseOrderResponse = services.get(PurchaseOrderArrayListBO.class, param, ygtHeaderParms);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (getPurchaseOrderResponse != null) {
                String authToken = getPurchaseOrderResponse.getAuthToken();
                if (authToken != null) {
                    editor.putString(ISharedPreferencesUtil.AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (getPurchaseOrderResponse.getAppStatusCode() == Constants.APP_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                    purchaseOrderArrayListBO = (PurchaseOrderArrayListBO) getPurchaseOrderResponse.getPayload();
                    poHeadersBOs = purchaseOrderArrayListBO.getPurchaseOrderList();
                    if (poHeadersBOs != null) {
                        simplePurchaseOrderAdapter = new SimplePurchaseOrderAdapter(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this, poHeadersBOs);
                        purchaseOrderListView.setAdapter(simplePurchaseOrderAdapter);
                    } else {
                        ExceptionMessages.showAlertDialog(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this, "No response from server", "Unable to get records", true);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (poHeadersBOs != null) {
                        poHeadersBOs.clear();
                        simplePurchaseOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ExceptionMessages.showAlertDialog(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.this, IExceptionUtil.NULL_RESPONSE_TITLE, IExceptionUtil.NULL_RESPONSE_MESSAGE, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My error output is like this:

```
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.yougotag.pharmainventory, PID: 12980
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.ygt.aroga.common.bo.PoHeadersBO
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.yougotag.pharmatenant.SimplePurchaseOrderActivity$5.onItemClick(SimplePurchaseOrderActivity.java:181)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-17 15:20:58.824 12980-12980/com.yougotag.pharmainventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the main error is happening in class is i commented in activity. Some classes it is working.Here it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get your data from the object that underly your **Adapter** and not from the ListView.

So if your Adapaters data source is poHeadersBOs, you should get it from there:

```
PoHeadersBO poHeadersBOsItem = poHeadersBOs.get(position);
```

Comment: thank you so much... really very happy... i am struggling from morning ... your solution is very very nice... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing this:

```
Object obj = purchaseOrderListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

to

```
Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.ygt.aroga.common.bo.PoHeadersBO came at String purchaseOrderNumber = ((PoHeadersBO) obj).getPoNumber().toString();

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the PoHeadersBO object onItem click